# VSCode on Mac - dockerServerReadyAction openExternally and ServerReadyAction openExternally in launch.json Doesn't Open Browser

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm using Visual Studio Code on a Mac with an M1 chip.

I've never been able to get VS code to launch my site when I hit debug.

I have this section in my launch.json file (I added it using this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/overview)

```
{
  "name": "Docker .NET Launch",
  "type": "docker",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
  "netCore": {
    "appProject": "${workspaceFolder}/api.csproj"
  },

}
```

I wanted to open this in a browser when I start debugging. After reading [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-common)

I set my docker container to expose 7007 in tasks

```
{
  "type": "docker-run",
  "label": "docker-run: debug",
  "dependsOn": ["docker-build: debug"],
  "dockerRun": {
    "ports": [{ "hostPort": 7001, "containerPort": 7001 }],
    "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://+:7001;http://+:7000"
  },
  "netCore": {
    "appProject": "${workspaceFolder}/yvr.api.csproj",
    "enableDebugging": true,
    "configureSsl": true
  }
},
```

then added the following to my launch profile

```
{
  "name": "Docker .NET Launch",
  "type": "docker",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
  "netCore": {
    "appProject": "${workspaceFolder}/api.csproj"
  },

 {
  "dockerServerReadyAction": {
    "action": "openExternally",
    "containerName": "[mycontainer]",
    "uriFormat": "https://localhost:7001/swagger/"
  }
```

Navigating to https://localhost:7001/swagger/ shows my running api, but I want the browser to open to the specified url automatically.

I am using docker, but this launch configuration also doesn't launch a browser (even though the site runs fine if you navigate to it manually.)

```
{
  "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
  "type": "coreclr",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "build",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net7.0/${workspaceFolderBasename}.dll",
  "args": [],
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "stopAtEntry": false,
  "serverReadyAction": {
    "action": "openExternally",
    "killOnServerStop": true,
    "uriFormat": "%s/swagger/",
    "pattern": "\\bNow listening on port:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
  },
  "postDebugTask": "npx-kill",
  "env": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "justMyCode": true,
  "sourceFileMap": {
    "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
  }
},
```

Is there a known issue with launching a browser from launch.json on some systems, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My work-around was adding a shell script task to open a browser from the command line.

This only works with a hard-coded port number.

I made the open task depend on the docker-run task that I was using before.

Added task:

```
{
  "label": "docker-run: debug-open",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "open https://localhost:7001/swagger/index.html",

  "dependsOn": ["docker-run: debug"]
},
```

changed launch.json

```
{
  "name": "Docker .NET Launch",
  "type": "docker",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug-open",
  "netCore": {
    "appProject": "[project]"
  }
},
```